# How to filter records in WHERE condition based on a SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, operators, case, conditional-statements

I have following case statement used to load **codes** table. I have to find count of records loaded into **codes** table
with ***TRAN_CODE = 7 when [gli-src] = '8'***

```
INSERT INTO codes 
    SELECT CASE 
             WHEN [cash-amt] > 0 THEN '1' 
             WHEN [prod-n] = '42' 
                  AND [tran-code] IN ( '-1', '-2', '-3' ) THEN '17' 
             WHEN [gli-src] = '8' THEN '7' 
             WHEN [prod-n] = '42' 
                  AND [gli-src] = 'L' 
                  AND [tran-code] IN ( '1', '2', '3' ) THEN '7' 
             WHEN [gli-src] = 'L' 
                  AND [prod-n] = '60' 
                  AND [tran-code] IN ( '4', '5', '6' ) THEN '7' 
             ELSE '4' 
           END AS TRAN_CODE 
    FROM   txn
```

This is what I have tried although I am confused how to filter out other case conditions.

```
select COUNT(1) from  txn
where [CASH-AMT] <= 0 
and
.
.
.
. ????
and [gli-src] = '8'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (  SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN [cash-amt] > 0 THEN '1' 
                 WHEN [prod-n] = '42' 
                      AND [tran-code] IN ( '-1', '-2', '-3' ) THEN '17' 
                 WHEN [gli-src] = '8' THEN '7' 
                 WHEN [prod-n] = '42' 
                      AND [gli-src] = 'L' 
                      AND [tran-code] IN ( '1', '2', '3' ) THEN '7' 
                 WHEN [gli-src] = 'L' 
                      AND [prod-n] = '60' 
                      AND [tran-code] IN ( '4', '5', '6' ) THEN '7' 
                 ELSE '4' 
               END AS TRAN_CODE, 
               [CASH-AMT],
               [gli-src]
        FROM   txn) AS T
WHERE [CASH-AMT] <= 0 
AND [gli-src] = '8'
AND TRAN_CODE = 7
```

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi What do you mean?, I don't understand your question